# Negative data for log transformation

Tags: forecasting, fisher-transform

I am analysing data on hourly electricity prices to try to do some forecasting, in my dataset I have mostly positive values, but some negative, around 20 per region for the two year duration. I want to do autoregressive (AR) forecast of this data, that is, trying to explain future prices based on previous prices.

I might want to add other variables such as weather forecasts later but for now I will concentrate on what I described above.
[image: Descriptive statistics]

Here is a example of the distribution:
[image: Histogram]

I want to transform this data to be able to do forecasts but I can't do log since I have negative values. I have read that i could add a constant (x+1) -> min. x is close to 0, or min. x is 1 and then do the log, I have also read that I could do a fisher transformation to get a better distribution. I am turning to you for some suggestions on what would be best practise in this case.

If you need some other measures I just ask and I will provide.

All the best

Comment: this is not really a statistical question.  Please think about what is the relationship between prices and  the other variables that you are interested in. (you don't explain whether price is an input or output) [ and update the question with those details].  There is no need to log data *just* because it is skewed.

Comment: I did edit my post now, I do not have other variables right now but I want to use a AR model to predict future prices based on previous prices.

Comment: the comments of the duplicate post should also be helpful.  but essentially you should aim to get the right functional form. a quick google : https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/29958/ ..."Moreover, this transformation might be in general more appropriate for power prices than the log transformation, considering fundamentals of power price formation. Eventually, a thorough treatment of negative prices is indispensable since they significantly affect business"